# Chess engine in C

Tags: c, artificial-intelligence, chess

I'm a 17 year old high school student who just started to learn C programming 1 week ago. I've also had some very basic experience in web design(+ a little web programming with javascript and php. I once made a website with contact form). 
Anyway, I'm very interested in AI and as a school project, I thought that i'll build a chess engine and a robotic arm that physically moves the pieces. 
Now, my deadline for which i have to finish the engine is 7 months away, (and the arm has to be completed in a year). 
Do you think it's feasible for a total beginner to program a chess engine in 7 months(and eventually build a robotic arm using that engine?)
Thank you very much!

Comment: I think that's pretty ambitious to be honest. One or the other, but why both?

Comment: There is a third part to this -- how will you handle input? In other words, how will your program know what move its (presumably human) opponent made?

Comment: If the move will be set as text input, he could save some time in some easy game. But in chess it the price of UI is unsignificant comparably to even the most primitive AI.

Comment: BTW, it seems to me, that the question could be moved to Programmers server.

Comment: I'm glad there was no Internet when I was 17.  Jeez, go for it.  Only way you're going to find out what you can do and what is practical.  Don't ask the pundits, only ask for help when you get stuck.

Comment: I'd avoid telling your teacher something concrete like "a chess playing robot" which sounds like setting yourself up to fail.  Instead, pick either robotic control, or AI as an interest area, and spend the year building what you can build, and then demo the interesting things you learned, and the capabilities you've implemented.  If you're interested in AI, can I suggest you check out Prolog, and LISP.  If you're interested in robotics, I think you should stick with C.  Frankly, C's not the language to learn AI with, it's a wonderful systems language for hardware and OS projects though.

Comment: You need about 7 years to do it.

Answer (score 2):

lol, great ambition, but it will take a hurculean effort on your part to get it done. Building the engine itself in your spare time will take quite a bit, as the AI for a chess game is pretty complicated, you have to tell the program to think ahead at least 7 moves with an end goal in mind, not to mention you will have to program the piece that interacts with the robot arm. You could theoretically cheat/not reinvent the wheel by utilizing some open source chess game and save yourself a few months of programming just in that piece.

Comment: Are you saying that i'd be impossible for me to program the engine myself in 7 months? (The reason i want to program the engine myself is that i want to gain experience in programming not just completing my school project).

Comment: No, not impossible, just a lot of work and learning. When you learn and program at the same time you go about 10x slower. I am just saying be prepared for a big project on your hands. Every time you find something you dont know about programming you have to go read, learn, and troubleshoot until you figure it out. Start hitting the books :)

Comment: It can take years to get a good sense of proper programming practices as well, be prepared to get errors that make no sense, and to top it all off are very difficult to figure out unless you have someone who can read the code for you and aid you. Good luck, i like your efforts :)

Comment: Probably, I'm sorry to say.  You can't just "program" the engine: you first need to become knowledgeable about AI and, in particular, the AI techniques for chess.  Then, I assume, you'll need to learn electronics and interfacing for the robot arm, etc., etc.  You've got very minimal programming experience and you probably have other classes to take in high school.  I know you're a Geek kid, but slow down, learn programming well not quickly, and stop and smell the roses - this is the best time of your life.

Comment: And visit the http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ site. You'll need the answers to theoretical questions or such as where to find info on...

Comment: Hm, thank you all for your quick replies! Ok, you kind of brought me back to earth with your reasoning and i decided that i won't try to make the arm but as i've already decleared that i'll make the engine for the project (the project is obligatory if i want to graduate) and i can't change my decision, i think i'll just have to get it done somehow.\n Again, thank you for your responses.d !

Answer (score 1):

I think, that it is better to choose some real task to start with for practice. Of course, you can divide the task in steps. But in chess the first step - GUI - is real for you. But the second - the most primitive AI - is extremely hard. It is the specific of the game.

If you take reversi/othello as the subject game, then creating a very primitive AI could be possible. I don't believe that you can manage recursive thinking, but one-step thinking, with evaluation of the positions and of course, the GUI for the game is possible. But you will have to work really hard. If you are interested, I could give you a pair of advices for this game realzation - I did it myself twice on different machines. But robotic hand is out of question.

Of course, if you are a genius, you can manage everything. ( I am not joking. You can never tell...)

And C is not the best language for AI. It is not even one of better ones.

Comment: Heh , thanks Hanz (and everyone else too ofcourse:d). I really began to feel sorry for myself before i read your post:d. But yeah, i'll just have to do it or i won't graduate :d